# JAVA - Find files located in different packages

Tags: java, eclipse, relative-path

How can i find files which are located in different packages of the same project? 
My Eclipse package is organized as follow:

There are these folders:

> - src/main/java
> - input

into the folder `src/main/java` i have the package main which contains my `Main class`, while into the input folder i have an `.xml` file which i want to edit from the Main. My problem is how can i know the relative path of my `.xml` file in the input folder from my `Main` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".." in the relative path to go to the folder above for example in your case : ../../../input/your.xml to get to the xml

Comment: which method can i use to achieve this ?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: And as filepath you can just use "../../../input/your.xml"

Answer (score 0):

You are terribly wrong. It doesn't matter where your source file or class file located. Only thing is from where you are running your program from that location, you can calculate the relative path for the particular xml file.
Basically if you are running from eclipse the project root directory should be your project root, not under src/classes. You write below to see your current directory, and based on that you can create/modify your relative path to your xml.

```
Path path = Paths.get("");
System.out.println("REL PATH" + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```